# What are the steps in eliminating recommendation questions?

Tags: discussion

In the immediate aftermath to [this discussion](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/656/1749), there seems to be somewhat of a consensus to ban game recommendation questions. An enthusiastic new moderator (congratulations, btw!) has done quite a bit of recommendation-related re-tagging. What I'm wondering is essentially what I can do to help the mods clean.

Clearly we will be strongly discouraging future recommendation questions. What is to be done with the ones currently out? Should they be closed / locked? If I find an old recommendation question not tagged as such (e.g. [this one](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/1619/1749)) should I add a [recommendations](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendations) tag, or flag it, or vote to close, or just ignore it?

Answer (score 5):

We (your new moderators) have been discussing this quite a bit. As you noticed, I went through and removed the [recommendations](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendations) tag from those questions where it was being used incorrectly.

Please do go ahead and add the [recommendations](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendations) tag to any old question you find which needs it.

Since we haven't heard any compelling argument here on meta in favour of these questions, and we believe they are actively harmful, we plan to close the existing recommendation questions quite soon. We'll be insta-closing future game recommendation questions of the form "what is a good game for x?".  The [FAQ](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/faq) will also be modified to reflect this.

**However**, remember that it's still possible to ask about the properties of games in a way that is acceptable! For example, the question [Good games for playing in a pool](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/3271/good-games-for-playing-in-a-pool), could be rewritten like this:

> What properties would a board game need to be successfully played in a swimming pool?

A good answer might talk about lamination, problems with wind, counters etc. It would be perfectly acceptable to mention games as examples to back up these general points.

Game recommendations and other opinion-based discussions are also ideal fodder for the [general B&CG chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49/board-and-card-games), so we do still have a place where we can find out about cool new games.