# Was this question a game recommendation question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[What board or card games simulate psychological warfare?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/27395/409) asks for games which meet some specific criteria. (It's now deleted, but the details don't really affect this question.) Is this a [game recommendation](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/why-are-game-recommendation-questions-off-topic), or does the fact that it doesn't ask anything like which ones are good/better/best avoid that pitfall?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is still a game recommendation question.

A game recommendation question is simply one which asks for answers which are (a list of) games meeting some criteria. If you ask for the best ones, you're additionally making it opinion-based; if you don't, you're making it broader by inviting *all* of them, not just good ones. Either way, you're in the situation we're trying to avoid: a potentially long list of answers, with no good way to decide which ones are good to upvote and which aren't. That is, the presence of the word "recommendation" does not mean that this is limited to questions which are asking for explicit "I think X is good" answers, it's just a general category.

Note that we've decided that *all* game recommendation questions are off-topic. It's true that perhaps some of them are sufficiently specific that they won't actually have a long list of answers, and those wouldn't really be so bad to have. Unfortunately it can be very difficult to tell which ones those are, and we don't want to get into debates about where to draw the line, so we've simply deemed them all off-topic. This is something that could be revisited if desired, but it's the current state of affairs.