# Is StackExchange a good place to get the word out on a new game?

Tags: discussion

I have created a new game, can I announce my website here?  Where can I go to get the word out?  Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

No, it isn't.

This is a Q&A site (see the [tour](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tour)), so anything you post needs to either be a specific question (i.e. not "do you like my game") or an answer to an existing question.

Additionally, [unsolicited self-promotion is frowned upon](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/promotion), so it generally won't be appropriate to promote anything here. You're welcome to mention a game you've made if it's part of a direct answer to a question and you disclose your affiliation, but that's not something that comes up often; people tend to ask questions about existing games, and [game recommendation questions are off-topic](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/why-are-game-recommendation-questions-off-topic).

Comment: That being said, I would definitely encourage players to ask their questions here - that's how communities start!

Comment: Indeed. Within reason, you can also ask and self-answer questions about the game. For example, if you discover unclear/missing/incorrect things in the rules, you could use self-answered questions as a way to publish errata. (But be sure to disclose your affiliation and don't go crazy with it; if you post a lot of things that are easily answered by the game's rules that'd probably be spam.)

Answer (score 1):

One thing you are allowed to do is put anything you like in your profile (as long as its not offensive). So you can put your website address in there, and as much blurb as you like about it.

Of course, people are unlikely to read your profile unless you post lots of high quality answers. Which is good, because we'd like you to become a member of the site, not just post something about your game and then disappear.